# Issue when creating an item with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I am having the following issue when trying to create an item using sequelize:

Executing (default): INSERT INTO productos (id_productos,idcolor,producto,idmarca,precio,descripcion,idtalle,idcategoria_producto,cantidad_stock) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); (node:14492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error at Query.run (C:\Users\DAMIAN\Desktop\Node\Luna\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:46:25) at C:\Users\DAMIAN\Desktop\Node\Luna\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:626:28 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) at async MySQLQueryInterface.insert (C:\Users\DAMIAN\Desktop\Node\Luna\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:749:21)

I understand that the error is because I did not add the catch in the function, but I want to know why the function is failing.

Here is the controller:

```
create: (req, res) => {

    db.Producto.create({
        producto: req.body.name_product,
        idcategoria_producto: req.body.category_product,
        idcolor: req.body.color_product,
        idmarca: req.body.brand_product,
        precio: req.body.price_product,
        descripcion: req.body.descript_product,
        idtalle: req.body.size_product,
        cantidad_stock: req.body.quantity_product
    })
    
    res.redirect("/")
}
```

The association of the product I am trying to create:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Producto";
    
    let cols = {
        id_productos: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        idcolor: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        producto: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(45)
        },
        idmarca: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        precio: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(255)
        },
        idtalle: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        idcategoria_producto: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        cantidad_stock: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "productos",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Producto = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Producto.associate = function(models){

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Marca, {
            as: "marca",
            foreignKey:"idmarca"
        })

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Color, {
            as: "color",
            foreignKey:"idcolor"
        })

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Categoria, {
            as: "categoria",
            foreignKey:"idcategoria_producto"
        })

        Producto.belongsTo(models.Talle, {
            as: "talles",
            foreignKey:"idtalle"
        })

        Producto.hasMany(models.Carrito, {
            as: "producto-carrito",
            foreignKey: "idproducto"
        })

        Producto.hasMany(models.Facturas, {
            as: "producto-facturas",
            foreignKey: "id_producto_facturas"
        })}

    return Producto
}
```

And the associations of the foreing keys:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Talle";
    let cols = {
        id_talles: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        talles: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(10)
        },
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "talles",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Talle = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Talle.associate = function(models){
        Talle.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-talle",
            foreignKey: "idtalle"
        })}
        
    return Talle
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Categoria";
    let cols = {
        id_categoria_producto: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        categoria_producto: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(20)
        },
        temporada: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(20)
        }
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "categoria_producto",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Categoria = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Categoria.associate = function(models){
        Categoria.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-categoria",
            foreignKey: "idcategoria_producto"
        })}
        
    return Categoria
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Color";
    let cols = {
        id_colores: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        nombre_color: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(20)
        }
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "colores_productos",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Color = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Color.associate = function(models){
        Color.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-color",
            foreignKey: "idcolor"
        })}

    return Color
}

----------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Marca";
    let cols = {
        id_marcas: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        marcas: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(30)
        },
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "marcas",
        timestamps: false
    }
    let Marca = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Marca.associate = function(models){
        Marca.hasMany(models.Producto, {
            as: "productos-marcas",
            foreignKey: "idmarca"
        })}
        
    return Marca
}
```

Probably is a silly mistake, but I don´t find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding a `catch` will be a good idea, as it should give you more information on the cause of the error, in the error object it catches.

Comment: Thank you so much @tromgy, I found the mistake by reading the information provided by the error in the catch.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and i resolved it by editing my

```
db.sequelize.sync()
```

to

```
db.sequelize.sync().then((e)=>{console.log(e) }).catch((e )=>{ console.log(e) });
```

**REASON**
db.sync() is an asyncronous method and so needs to be handle asynchronously using `.then()` and `.catch()`